# Angular doesn't set form to valid with a select statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm having a form that uses a select to show what already is selected in the database. So my localTypesObject is an item that is already selected. When the user selects another one that localTypesObject is changed.

```
<select id="types" required multiple class="form-control" ng-model="localTypesObject" ng-options="item as item.getType() for item in types"></select>
```

Now I thought I could disable my submit button like always with ng-disabled like this:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

but the button never enables except when the user selects another item or reselect the already selected. Then the form is set to valid.

How can I fix this? It seems to me that angular doesn't see if the ng-model is empty or not.

**EDIT:**

This the function that saves ALL the types in my parse database.

```
$scope.applyTypes = function (result) {
    $scope.types = result;
}
```

Where result is my result from Parse service.

This is a piece that is called when I have my specific object, then I loop to see what type must already be selected.

```
    for(var indexAllTypes = 0; indexAllTypes < $scope.types.length; indexAllTypes++){
        for(var indexMatchedTypes = 0; indexMatchedTypes < result.getTypes().length; indexMatchedTypes++){
            if($scope.types[indexAllTypes].getType() == result.getTypes()[indexMatchedTypes].getType()){
                $scope.localTypesObject.push($scope.types[indexAllTypes]);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is where I check if some element in my $scope.types is already selected.

As you can see I just push the same object types in my scope.localTypesObject.

Output before anything is clicked:

[image]

Output after clicking on something:

[image]

Comment: The item has to the same object that is there in `types` collection. Angular will do object equal to match your `localTypesObject` and an item from the types array.

Comment: The localTypeSObject is of the same type.

Comment: Can you share the code where you do initial assignment. It need to be the same object rather than type,

Comment: Can you please give us the output of `angular.element(types).scope().localTypesObject` before and after clicking the same element?

Comment: You can try to put a default value so your ng-model won't be empty.
$scope.localTypesObject = // your value;
Edit: Oh sorry didn't see , so share us the code please :)

Comment: @carton he already did that.

Comment: I've shared my code. When I print this angular.element(types).scope().localTypesObject it gives me a whole array. Is there something particular you want?

Comment: @user1007522 And what does it print after clicking an element? I think it should print a single element instead of an array...

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but how can I listen to a single click in the select statement? ( I'm quite new to angular ) nvm found it ng-change. Second

Comment: Oh it's a `multiple` select, sorry. So the array may be correct. How many elements are selected by default? What do you mean by "listen to a single click"? Can you tell me if there is a difference in `angular.element(types).scope().localTypesObject` *before* and *after* selecting an element?

Comment: I've added screenshots before and after clicking something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78320/discussion-between-camusensei-and-user1007522).

Comment: here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TXPO9gA7Y3Y5arQKzRmS?p=preview)...

Comment: Thanks but why do I need to convert my array of Types to objects?